# How to auto-redirect to login after an unauthorized api request (ex. when token has expired)? - Nuxt Auth module

Tags: authentication, module, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

How to redirect to login page after an unauthorized request with Nuxt Auth Module in Universal Mode (when the token has expired or is no longer valid for exemple) ?
In my nuxt project, when I am logged in and my token deleted or expired, I am redirected only when I refresh the page. If not, my api calls return 403 errors, but I can still navigate in the secured pages, until I refresh.

Here is my Middleware :

```
export default function ({ $auth, redirect, route, store }) {
  if (!$auth.user || !$auth.loggedIn || !$auth.user.role.includes('admin')) {
    return redirect('/admin/login?r=' + route.fullPath.replace('/admin/', ''))
  }
}
```

-- edit :
I Have fix my problem by changing my middleware to this :

```
export default async function ({ $auth, redirect, route }) {
  await $auth.fetchUser()

  if (!$auth.loggedIn || !$auth.user.role.includes('admin')) {
    return redirect('/admin/login?r=' + route.fullPath.replace('/admin/', ''))
  }
}
```

Is this the proprer way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
export default function ({ $auth, redirect }) {
    if (process.client) {
        if (!$auth.loggedIn || !$auth.user.role.includes('admin')) {
            redirect('/admin/login')
        }
    }
}
```

Dont forget to add middleware to your layout or pages

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly, it doesn't work. The middleware is actually call every time on the client side, but it is like the $auth.loggedIn still is true until I refresh the page. One way to test this, is to open two pages in the browser of the secured admin and then logout on one of them. In that page, the logout will be successfull and $auth.loggedIn will be equal to false, but in the other one $auth.loggedIn will still be true even if all request no longer work. Is there a way to force refresh $auth.loggedIn state without refreshing the page ?

Comment: `$auth.logout ()` or `$auth.reset()` maybe help you

Comment: Actually `loggedIn` set in `setUser()` method : `setState('loggedIn', Boolean(user))`, did you check can retrieve user while you logged out?

Comment: I can't retrieve the user after logged out in the browser tab I logged out, but if I have an other browser tab, the user is still set until I refresh the page. I have just found that if I add `await $auth.fetchUser()` in my middleware, now that work like expected (the user is undefined and I am logged out). But, is this the right way to do it (force re-fetch on every admin route change), or I should be watching for 401 errors on my request and force refresh user state only in thoses cases ? https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/auth.html#fetchuser

Answer (score 0):

I am using plugin

add in nuxt.config.js

```
plugins: [
    '~/plugins/axios',
],
```

create in plugins folder, if not exist.. create manually plugins/axios.js

replace with this

```
export default function ({ $axios, redirect }: { $axios:any, redirect:any }) {
    $axios.onRequest((config: any) => {
        console.log('Making request to ' + config.url)
    })
  
    $axios.onError((error: any) => {
      const code = parseInt(error.response && error.response.status)
      if (code === 400) {
        redirect('/400')
      } else if (code === 401) { // Unauthorized
        if (window.location.pathname !== '/login') {
            window.location.href = "/login";
        }
      }
    })
}
```

i am not using middleware

Comment: Hello ! The code your suggesting doesn't work in my case. If I console.log(code), the result is NAN and in my console the following message : fetch.client.js?2293:75 Error in fetch(): ExpiredAuthSessionError: Both token and refresh token have expired. Your request was aborted

Comment: I think my problem is from the backend. I am using devise-jwt for authentification and it seem to not handle refresh token pattern : https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt/issues/7

Comment: HI!... im sorry for your problem... im using refresh_token on my app with nuxt/auth, it's not working, then i create refresh_token manually